# how difficult is it to link an address to an account?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, cpp-ethereum, ethereumj

Every wallet can generate as many addresses as I want in order to obfuscate the origin and destination of transactions.

But each account has exactly one key-pair and it is trivial to get the public key from the address.

Am I correct in assuming that it would be fairly easy to create a list of all the addresses belonging to a public key and by extension to an account? Or is there something I am missing?

The use case for such a database would be for law enforcement to find out who has sent money to whom, for example.

Comment: Re: "_it is trivial to get the public key from the address_" - the public key _is_ the address. Re: "_to create a list of all the accounts belonging to a public key and by extension to an account_" - one account has one public key. Or are you talking about accounts owning contracts?

Comment: I changed the text. Thank you for your comment. It is the list of addresses for an account that I would like to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything on the blockchain is public. Every transaction can be traced and accounts can easily be linked.

This is true of Bitcoin as well, and most other cryptocurrencies.

In the future, however, we will be able to verify transactions from the Zcash blockchain, which preserves privacy using zkSNARKS. This will allow decentralized exchange between the two, which will make anonymization much easier. In the slightly more distant future, we hope to add zkSNARKS to Ethereum itself, providing privacy to users natively.

See https://github.com/ConsenSys/Project-Alchemy for the beginnings of the Zcash relay and https://github.com/zcash/babyzoe for the zkSNARK work

Answer (score 1):

you are talking about pseudoanonimity for the cryptocurrencies, there is a lot of papers to read about this subject.

in your question you have two false statements:

1-`it is trivial to get the public key from the address`. you cannot get a pub key from an addresse

2-`assuming that it would be fairly easy to create a list of all the addresses belonging to a public key`=> the pub key isn't brodcasted in the network it is used only as seed for address.

the pseudo anonimity is rather depending on linking accounts or on information's leak on the internet where for exemple you publish your addresse on your blog.
there is come solution to this problem : Mixing transactions,zeroknowledge, etc.

Comment: Note that once you spend *from* an address, the public key is revealed. The public key is most certainly broadcasted, unless you are talking about BIP 32 wallets, which are not widely implemented in Ethereum

Comment: Well, when you sign a transaction, the public key can be easily derived from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult with the help of blockchain analysis solutions. Resources used for it range from blockchain explorers to costly B2B tools. There are also hybrid solutions like Cryptohound. The latter works well on tracing money flows from various addresses (BTC/ETH up to date), providing token and trading analytics. It has some nice widgets for blockchain analytics:

Graph Widget for the viewing, expanding and exploring of the transactions and relationships of any searched addresses
Balance Widget summarizes the list and total value of all tokens held over some time
Statement Widget supports the Graph Widget by providing more details related to all incoming and outgoing transactions, with historical balances viewed in the currency of your choice.

Check available solutions; maybe it would be helpful for your future researches.